# Unable to return chrome://downloads/ list from a Protractor download test case

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, download, protractor

Allright , so I had this function written a while ago and it was working well.
Basically I'm downloading a file and then checking if there is n items in chrome://downloads/ and if the filename matches

```
this.checkDownload = async function checkDownload(fileNameRegEx) {
    var regex = new RegExp(fileNameRegEx);
    if ((await browser.getCapabilities()).get('browserName') === 'chrome') {
        await browser.get('chrome://downloads/');
        const items = await browser.executeScript('return downloads.Manager.get().items_');
        expect(items.length).toBe(1);
        expect(items[0].file_name).toMatch(regex);
    }
};
```

And today I had to reuse it and it throws an error :

> Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

I think the issue is that downloads.**Manager** is undefined.
Has there been anything changes to Chrome api? Something has a new name?
I couldnt find any documentation on this in the official chrome patch notes.
I tried looking through the downloads object but I could not find any property/method that lists downloaded items.

Comment: Chrome Version 80.0.3987.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether there are downloads and they are done, this works:

```
var items = document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('#downloadsList downloads-item');
  if (Array.from(items).every(i => i.shadowRoot.querySelector('#progress') == null || i.shadowRoot.querySelector('#progress').value === 100))
    return Array.from(items).reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr.shadowRoot.querySelector('div#content #file-link').href], []);
```

My code that was based on `downloads.Manager` broke too... I'd be great to have some information why it was removed.

**edit**: See here, someone had the same issue and there's a fix: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/28267973?hl=en

Comment: Thanks!
This is exactly what I was looking for.
P.S the guy asking there was me :)

Comment: The link you provided is dead now. Would be great to get an explanation or solution

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first element (or change selector to get any other element) via selector:

```
const element = browser.executeScript("return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('a');");
```

Or get the text of the element via adding `.innerText` at the end

```
const elementWithText = browser.executeScript("return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('a').innerText;");
```

Look at the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51346897/9332160

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to whether it has changed recently or not but I noticed that getCabilities returns a Map as a child of the main object. It could be the `get()` associated with this part which is generating the error and not the one inside the execute script. Can you try adding `['map_'] like below

```
if ((await browser.getCapabilities())['map_'].get('browserName') === 'chrome') {
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined is from  "'return downloads.Manager.get().items_'".
I tested on Chrome version 7x and it returns and object, but is undefined in 8x.
My guess is that they deprecated it or something.
Thanks for the suggestion though!